# Can't create a US State entity because of "in"

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson

I am trying to create a US State entity that contains all the 2 letter state codes and their names as synonyms. I am using this to match responses and associate context variables via slots. When a user says things like "I live in Texas", Watson is matching both @state:IN and @state:TX.

Should Watson be able to differentiate in this scenario via context or part of speech?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal entities might not help you here, as it will pick both the full name and short codes at the same time. Try the system entities and use the **@sys-location**. This will identify the states properly, but you will have to take care of the mapping of the full state name with the two-letter state code. You can do this in your application easily via a JSON file with key-value pairs like below.

```
{
    "Texas": "TX",
    "Indiana": "IN",
    "California": "CL"
}
```